# How did Jessica Jones know about Kilgrave's weakness?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

Jessica, Trish and Simpson made a plan how to catch Kilgrave:

> They planned to put him in the chamber which is completely isolated. Even sound can't pass through it. However, later she talks happily to him via a microphone. They do this because his powers do not work if he does not directly speak to you. In a way he is like a virus.

But how could they have known this would work before trying it? Sure, she talked to him via a cellphone before, but it could have been that he just needed to be nearby for his powers to work.

How did they know beforehand about this fact?

Answer (score 8):

From [SciFi Stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109679) on similar question :

> Jessica had a history with Kilgrave that seemed to have lasted for
> quite a while. In that time, she presumably paid close attention to
> how his powers worked. She seemed to know quite a bit about them from
> the very start of the show, including:
>
> - You had to be physically "near" him to affected
> - They only lasted ~10 hours
> - You could work around them by taking them literally
>
> It's never explained outright, but we're lead to believe that she has
> figured out roughly *how* his powers work, though she doesn't quite
> understand why. I believe early on they may have even mentioned the
> theory that it was *pheromone* based. That would include the fact that
> people needed to be in the same "air space" as him to be affected.
>
> ([Answer by Mike Edenfield](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109680/57005))

Comment: questions like this are perfectly fine on either site; SF&F often has a better grasp on the source material, if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: This kind of question are on topic on both the sites, SFF might give you more insight about comic part but here the answer will be more on production, direction and story side .  But deliberate cross posting is not allowed but duplicate among different SE are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Per my answer to a [similar question on SFF:SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109679/how-did-jessica-jones-know-that-the-hermetically-sealed-room-would-be-safe);

---

**It was a lucky coincidence.** Note that Jessica's [original plan](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=marvels-jessica-jones-2015&episode=s01e05) was simply to keep Kilgrave sedated while she tries to work out her next move.

> **Jessica Jones:** *I'll keep him doped up, I just need a place to stash him.*

It's not until she finds out that the isolation room is hermetically sealed *and* soundproofed that she risks speaking to him, and **even then she insists on doing it alone** since she's the only person who seems to be able to resist him.

If it turned out to be control via magic (or line-of-sight or something else) then she seems reasonably confident she can resist him long enough to shock him and try something else.