# Why not protect against Kilgrave's powers in other ways?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

In *Jessica Jones* we discover how Kilgrave's powers really work: It is a virus.

Then why does Jessica not use some kind of helmet or even a whole suit like the CDC ones to avoid being controlled by him?

It seems much easier than creating a vaccine that could not work.

Comment: So the entire world wears these suits?..That's not really practical.

Comment: Highly related (if not a dupe) - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44539/how-did-jessica-jones-know-about-kilgraves-weakness

Comment: @Paulie_D no. just her to destroy him. And the question you point out is relevant but not answer my question

Comment: The point is that he can control **anyone** so he can threaten innocent people to make sure JJ won't hurt him even if she is immune.

Comment: Yeah but her sister wore headphones instead of air sealed helmet or so

Comment: The headphones prevented her from being able to hear the commands and actually being commanded, not from being susceptible to the virus.

Comment: @phantom42 i know. but as we saw, the headphones werent useful at all. the helmet wouldnt fell off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the show and described in her [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones).

> She possesses superhuman strength, as well as flight, and is known to block mind control because of her strength.

She is already able to block mind control, so there is no point for her to wear a suit.

Also Killgrave (The purple man) controls other people to do bad things to themselves, and he uses that to manipulate Jessica. As said in the comments, it wouldn't be too easy to make the whole world to wear suits...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but obviously I dont try to make a whole world wear a suit. just them to stop him

Comment: No problem =). Them who? You can't possibly know who is Killgrave gonna use against Jessica, He just uses random people...